# How to run tests cross-platform/browser using decorator in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, parallel-processing, cross-platform, saucelabs

I have a test suite as below:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

SAUCE_USERNAME = 'xxx'
SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
sauce = SauceClient(SAUCE_USERNAME, SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY)

browsers = [{"platform": "Mac OS X 10.9",
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "version": "31"},
        {"platform": "Windows 8.1",
         "browserName": "internet explorer",
         "version": "11"}]


def on_platforms(platforms):
    def decorator(base_class):
        module = sys.modules[base_class.__module__].__dict__
        for i, platform in enumerate(platforms):
            d = dict(base_class.__dict__)
            d['desired_capabilities'] = platform
            name = "%s_%s" % (base_class.__name__, i + 1)
            module[name] = new.classobj(name, (base_class,), d)
    return decorator

@on_platforms(browsers)
class MyTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.desired_capabilities['name'] = cls.id()
        sauce_url = "http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"
        cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        desired_capabilities=cls.desired_capabilities,
        command_executor=sauce_url % (SAUCE_USERNAME,SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY))
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_1from_sauce(self):
        pass

    def test_2from_sauce(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

My goal is to run test_1from_sauce and test_2from_sauce for browsers/platforms in browsers and ALSO I do want to do both of them in a row on the browser that is setup on setUpClass. To explain more, I want to open a browser and do both tests then quit that driver and start another driver.

Right now when I run this code, I get this error: 
TypeError: unbound method setUpClass() must be called with SeleniumSauce_2 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I know there should be a modification in class and subclass declaration but I do not know what should I do or what part should I change.

EDITED: I omitted the following line and it worked fine:

`cls.desired_capabilities['name'] = cls.id()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show in your question is missing the imports for `sys` and `new`. Secondly, the error I get when I run your code after adding the right imports is not what you report in your question but this:

```
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (__main__.MyTestSuite_1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 33, in setUpClass
    cls.desired_capabilities['name'] = cls.id()
TypeError: unbound method id() must be called with MyTestSuite_1 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I've omitted a second `ERROR` which is the same as above except that it is for `MyTestSuite_2` rather than `MyTestSuite_1`. The problem is pretty clear. You call the `id()` member of `cls` but `id()` is an **instance method** not a **class method** so it needs an instance of the class, not the class itself. I'm not sure what it is you want in the end but if you use this for your `setUpClass`, then the error no longer occurs and an attempt is made to connect:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.desired_capabilities['name'] = cls.__name__
    sauce_url = "http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"
    cls.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        desired_capabilities=cls.desired_capabilities,
        command_executor=sauce_url % (SAUCE_USERNAME, SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY))
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

The only modification is the first line of the method.

By the way, I don't get why you use `new.classobj`. For one thing, the `new` module is deprecated. Secondly, using the `type` built-in rather than `new.classobj` works.

Comment: Thanks @Louis both for the answer and your informations about new.classobj.